# How to convert a color video to 3d matrix in matlab?

Tags: matlab, matrix

I am new to matlab,I am trying to convert a color video to 3d matrix so that i can process the video.I have googled and tried [this](https://in.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/309431)

```
mov=uint8(vidHeight,vidWidth,nFrames);

xyloObj = VideoReader('01.avi');
vidWidth = xyloObj.Width;
nFrames = xyloObj.NumberOfFrames;
vidHeight = xyloObj.Height;

% Read one frame at a time.
for k = 1 : nFrames
  mov(:,:,k) = read(xyloObj, k);
end
```

But i am getting error as

```
Too many input arguments.
mov=uint8(vidHeight,vidWidth,nFrames);
```

So how can i do this in matlab?
My matlab version is **MATLAB R2014a**

Comment: You need to initialize the 3D matrix first. `mov=uint8(vidHeight,vidWidth,nFrames);`

Comment: @Eskapp but now getting error as "Too many input arguments.mov=uint8(vidHeight,vidWidth,nFrames);"

Comment: Can you update your question with the modified code?

Comment: @Eskapp yes i have updated

Comment: And try `mov = zeros(vidHeight, vidWidth, nFrames, 'uint8');` instead

Comment: But you need to declare `mov`, after declaring the arguments you are passing in. Just before the `for` loop

Comment: @Eskapp Preallocation has nothing to do with the original error and, as you've seen, `mov=uint8(...)` does not preallocate an array. The function `uint8` merely *converts* the elements of an existing array to `uint8`. The *original* problem, which is now overshadowed, is that each RGB frame is already 3D: height-by-width-by-3. Therefore `mov` must be 4D: `mov(:,:,:,k) = ...`. See https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/videoreader.read.html

Comment: @beaker thanks for your input, I have been confused by the link posted in the question that added this line. Sorry about this. By the way, in the link given in the question, the function `mmreader` is used to read the file, do you know if it makes a difference about the 4D frames? (The solution proposed there seems to use 3D frames...) I cannot find the function in the online documentation...

Comment: @Eskapp I don't know about `mmreader`, but the key line here is `"As long as the files are grayscale rather than full color..."`. If they frames are grayscale, they're 2D; if they're RGB, they're 3D.